# Karma Angular inject directives link function into root scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, karma-runner

Hi I am testing a directives named controller like so:

```
beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, $controller, _$httpBackend_) {
    $scope = $rootScope.$new();
    $http = _$httpBackend_;

    $controller('coreAppController', {$scope : $scope});

    $http.flush();
}));
```

The problem is the controller needs to access some functions within the directives `link` block.  Is it possible to inject this into the scope without compiling the full directive?

Comment: Please also post your directive-implementation. It depends on how you call the Functions on the `link`-Function of the directive.

Comment: it's declared within the directive `link : function($scope) {}` .

Comment: Yeah tahts clear since there is no other way. Im talking about those function that you call inside your controller. I need to see them to help you. So maybe just add the whole code of the directive to your post.

Comment: They're just functions declared within the link function attached to the scope : `$scope.open = function(){};` then executed in the controller `$scope.open()` .

Answer (score 0):

As I´ve read in your comments, your `Link`-Function adds the Functions you call inside your  Controller to the `scope`. This is not really a nice architecture, since a Directives Controller is usually used to let several directives communicate with each other, so from `Link` to `Controller`, not the other way around. If you wanna keep up with this and NEED that architecture, you should probably MOCK the Functions you wanna call from the link function - after all, its a Unit Test, so you should only test the most atmoic units and therefore dont need the whole directive.

Just do something like

```
beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, $controller, _$httpBackend_) {
   $scope = $rootScope.$new();
   $scope.MYSCOPEFUNCTION = jasmine.createSpy('MyFunctionMock');
   $http = _$httpBackend_;

   $controller('coreAppController', {$scope : $scope});

   $http.flush();
}));
```